# Deduce type of template type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

When writing generic functions for "iterator" ranges I usually do:

```
template <typename Iter> auto func(Iter &first, Iter &last)
{
    using IterType = typename std::decay<decltype(*first)>::type;
    ...
}
```

Another way seems to be:

```
template <typename Iter> auto func(Iter &first, Iter &last)
{
    using IterType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
    ...
}
```

And yet a third:

```
template <typename Iter> auto func(Iter &first, Iter &last)
{
    using IterType = typename Iter::value_type;
    ...
}
```

Without applying `iterator_traits`.

In theory, my functions should only receive iterators as `first` and `last` and the second form would ideally (imho) the most idiomatic way to get the type. But is using `typename std::decay<decltype(*first)>::type` the most generic idiom in order to not impose restrictions to `Iter` like having a `value_type` defined?

Comment: I think it is idiomatic to pass iterators by value.

Comment: If `iterator_traits` doesn't work for something, said something is not an iterator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The second is the most idiomatic one.

- The first does not work with proxies (std::vector < bool > )
- The third does not work with pointers.

Answer (score 10):

None of these are quite idiomatic; you should be passing iterators by value, not by reference. Here's the signature for for_each in gcc 4.9:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Function>
_Function
for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
```

As you can see, it's passed by value. Your functions will not work in the idiomatic usage:

```
func(v.begin(), v.end()); // error, binding non-const ref to rvalue!
```

Also, going through iterator_traits is more than just idiomatic, it's basically required. Insofar as the STL is concerned, such typedefs are defined solely through iterator_traits: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator. iterator_traits provides reasonable defaults for the generic case, but it can be specialized (as it is for pointers) to do different things. Not going through iterator_traits basically means someone could write a compliant iterator that worked with the STL but not your code.